# What is wrong with this function, that should make a geospatial query in mongo db?

Tags: php, mongodb, geospatial

I have this function that makes a geospatial query in mongodb - php. I don't know why, but it does not return anything. (I have a collection called EVENTS, that have inside, an array with two fields longitude, latitude and I have the user location coordinates). I want to query events that are around user position (1000 m distance). Do you know what is wrong with it?

```
public function findEventsByUsersLocation($lng, $lat){
    $c_events = $this->db->events;
    $c_events->find(array('lnglat'=> array('$near'=>array($lng, $lat),
                                    '$maxDistance' => 1000)));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, your should add `return` right before `$c_events->find()`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the return. Oleg is write!

```
public function findEventsByUsersLocation($lng, $lat){
$c_events = $this->db->events;
return $c_events->find(array('lnglat'=> array('$near'=>array($lng, $lat),
                                '$maxDistance' => 1000)));
```

}